# How to find positions of certain matrix elements in one matrix and, based upon these positions, delete elements in a different matrix of the same size

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a matrix m

```
m={{10,2},{20,3},{30,4},{40,5},{50,6}}
```

I also have a list n

```
list1={1,2,3,4,5}
```

and another matrix

```
p={{25,-23},{64,33},{77,74},{99,5},{200,68}}
```

I can find certain elements in matrix m with this statement

```
list2=Select[m,(10 < #[[1]] < 50 ) && (#[[2]] < 6) &]
```

and I get

```
{20,3},{30,4},{40,5}
```

I can also use

```
list2=DeleteCases[m , _?(10 < #[[1]] < 50 && #[[2]] < 6 &)];
```

Now, how can I get the position of those deleted items (or selected items) so I can use that information to trim down both the list1 and other matrix p to yield

```
{2,3,4}
```

and from matrix p

```
p={{64,33},{77,74},{99,5}}
```

I've tried to obtain position information about the deleted items using:

```
list3 = Position[m, _?(10 < #[[1]] < 50) && (#[[2]] < 6) &]
```

and

```
list3 = Position[m, (10 < #[[1]] < 50) && (#[[2]] < 6) &]
```

but I'm getting empty set all the time.

Thanks,

Comment: You have an operator precedent issue. Use `Position[m, _?((10 < #[[1]] < 50) && (#[[2]] < 6) &)]` instead. Looking into why this gives messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
selected = 10 < #[[1]] < 50 && #[[2]] < 6 & /@ m;
Pick[p, selected]
```

> `{{64, 33}, {77, 74}, {99, 5}}`

```
Pick[list1, selected]
```

> `{2, 3, 4}`

Of course, you can also use this on `m`: `Pick[m, selected]`.

To make your approach work you have to change a few things. As Edmund said, the `&` needs to go inside the parenthesis. Then you need another set of parenthesis to surround the `And` statement. You also need to set `Heads -> False` or it will try to match your pattern with the heads of subexpressions, in this case `List`. That will give errors because `List` doesn't have a first and a second part. Finally you also need to specify at what level the subexpressions exist. All in all:

```
selected = Position[m, _?((10 < #[[1]] < 50) && (#[[2]] < 6) &), {1}, Heads -> False]
Extract[p, selected]
```

> `{{64, 33}, {77, 74}, {99, 5}}`

Of course, this is based on the premise that you want to use the pattern in the question. As Edmund has shown, there are more appropriate patterns.

Comment: OK - yes that works great. without the {1}, and Heads->False, it is a no-go. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may use a named [`Pattern`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html) with a [`Condition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html) to get the [`Position`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html)s.The use [`Extract`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Extract.html) to collect them from `p`.

```
pos = Position[m, (v : {a_, b_}) /; (10 < a < 50 && b < 6)]
```

> ```
> {{2}, {3}, {4}}
> ```

Then

```
Extract[p, pos]
```

> ```
> {{64, 33}, {77, 74}, {99, 5}}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you - this works too. Can you recommend a place to read up on this syntax? I'm very unfamiliar with the /;.

Comment: @TomMozdzen I have given links in the answer.  Click on the function name or search the help in *Mathematica* or highlight the function and press F1 in *Mathematica*.  Note that you can evaluate code in the help and  add additional parameters in the help as well; it is interactive.